# Use submit button control in a child template in umbraco

Tags: c#, templates, controls, submit, umbraco

I learned that in umbraco, we have to use a master template for a custom user control. I have a custom form and a submit button. I created a control that sends an email once the 'submit" button is pressed. the control basically gets all the fields like name, address. It works when I create a new template and insert the macro.

However when I try to use it with a master template, it does not work. The submit button refreshes the page but never goes to my c# part where it sends the mail

and if I do this

```
     <form name="myform" target="_self" method="post" action="index">
```

it goes to the index page, but no email is sent.

But it works on a clean or new template. Is there a way to use custom control with master template in umbraco 4
EDIT -
This is how I am using macro

```
<form name="myform" target="_self" method="post" action="index">    
   <umbraco:Macro Alias="sendMail" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean, a custom controller? Are you using MVC in Umbraco 4, and if so, how?

Comment: I just create a new project in VS2010, and then create a web user control and use that controller in umbraco

Comment: A control is not the same thing as a controller. Be careful to use exact language or you will find it difficult to get help.

Comment: Thanks Evan... I will edit my posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code it looks like you are missing the `runat="server"` attribute on the form tag.

```
<form name="myform" runat="server">    
   <umbraco:Macro Alias="sendMail" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
</form>
```

By using the `runat=server` attribute the form tag will be rendered with the correct attributes. Note you can only have one `runat="server"` form on a page.

There's some more information on this concept on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim. Actualy My control has the runat tag. Either way, it doesn't work with the masterpage

Comment: Can you supply any more code examples? As it's really hard to tell what the issue is from the small snippets?

Comment: @EagleFox, you need a runat="server" on the form tag and no other attributes, just as Tim Saunders said. "All server controls must appear within a <form> tag, and the <form> tag must contain the runat="server" attribute. The runat="server" attribute indicates that the form should be processed on the server." (http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp)

Comment: Thanks everybody... the form tag on my master template was messing me up... it works fine now...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using ASP.NET WebForms. I have Umbraco sites in which I also use a Master Template and a Macro which contains a form. This should work normally.
What I notice is that you have set the "action" attribute which is ignored. Also the "method" attribute default value is "post" so you don't need to set both these properties.

An ASP.NET Webform is always posting to itself, so you can remove the "target" property here. I'm not sure that removing these "unwanted" attributes will solve your problem.

If not, are you using nested .NET Forms? That is throwing errors and strange behavior as well.